# How is `auto *x = new some_struct{};` an uninitialized variable?

Tags: c++, initialization, static-analysis

Recently, I decided to try out CodeInspector.

In my code, I've written the following:

```
auto *v4Addr = new sockaddr_in{};
```

Code Inspector has flagged this line (as well as a few other similar lines) as `Violation |  Critical/security | Uninitialized variable: v4Addr`

It is my understanding that `new some_struct{}` initializes the struct with 0s. Is there something I'm missing? Should I be using `new some_struct()` or something else instead?

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: I don't think its possible for an object declared with `auto` to be uninitialized, because initialization is required to determine the actual type (I would be interested to see a counter example though). However, what the pointer points to could still be uninitialized.

Comment: What does Code Inspector say if you use parenteces instead of braces?

Comment: N.B. The warning is talking about the pointer, not the `sockaddr_in` structure (unless that's a bug too)

Comment: You can just say `auto v4addr...` fyi.

Comment: @Taekahn `auto*` is better. It's good to be able to see that you have a raw pointer, and thus need to delete it later. Actually, `sockaddr* v4Addr = new sockaddr_ini{};` would be best. There is no need for `auto` here at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't.

CodeInspector is wrong.

You should report a bug to its authors.